# CSS scroll shadow not appearing on top of background colour

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design, box-shadow

I added shadows that appear while scrolling the table, but if the table has background colour the shadow doesn't show. (ref: http://lea.verou.me/2012/04/background-attachment-local/ found here on stackoverflow).

Anyone know how can I show the table scroll shadow effect on top of the table background colour?

```css
.pagewrap1 {
 width: 90%;
 background-color:orange;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

div.data {
 background-color:yellow;
}

table.data {
 border-width: 0px;
 width:750px;
 /*background-color:lightskyblue;*/
}
.auto-style2 {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.auto-style2b {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color:purple;
}

#cell01 {
 background-color:#99FFCC
}

#cell02 {
 background-color:#CCFFCC
}

#cell03 {
 background-color:#FFFFCC
}

#cell04 {
 background-color:aqua
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 740px) {

.pagewrap {
 background-color:blue;
}

.scroll {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 margin-left: 30px;
 background-image: 

    /* Shadows */ 
    linear-gradient(to right, yellow, yellow),
    linear-gradient(to left, yellow, yellow),
    /* Shadow covers */
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));

  background-position: left center, right center, left center, right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-size: 20px 100%, 20px 100%, 10px 100%, 10px 100%;

  /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;


}
.auto-style2b {
 position: absolute;
 left: 30px;
 width:25px;
}


table.data {
 width:100%; 
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>



</head>

<body>

<div class="pagewrap1">
<div class="data">
<div class="scroll">
<table class="data">
 <tr>
  <th class="auto-style2b">&nbsp;</th>
  <th style="width: 195px" class="auto-style2">column a</th>
  <th style="width: 195px" class="auto-style2">column b</th>
  <th style="width: 195px" class="auto-style2">column c</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th style="height: 120px;" class="auto-style2b">c1</th>
  <td style="height: 120px; width: 195px;" class="auto-style2" id="cell01">
  123456789123456<br />
  </td>
  <td style="height: 120px; width: 195px;" class="auto-style2" id="cell02">
  123456789123456789</td>
  <td style="height: 120px; width: 195px;" class="auto-style2" id="cell03">
  123456789123456789123456</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th class="auto-style2b">c2</th>
  <td style="width: 195px" class="auto-style2" id="cell04">5855</td>
  <td style="width: 195px" class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td style="width: 195px" class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th class="auto-style2b">c3</th>
  <td style="width: 195px" class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td style="width: 195px" class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td style="width: 195px" class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using opacity with background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); ? Looks like https://codepen.io/ramiro-ruiz/pen/YzKVOGK works